# Set a tag to track links from a visual basic app in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I hope I can explain myself.

See. I have this little program where I put a link to my site, what I want to know if there's some way to add a tag into the URL so Google Analytics can count the amount of visitors coming from that program.

Like when you parse the GET in php.

something like `http:\\www.stackoverflow.com\?something_to_google_analytics_to_read`

If this is possible, I assume that I need also to configure that Tag into Analytic's, or?

Thanks

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Comment: Well thank you... I really never used this before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SLaks pointed, I can find a step by step guide for create what I wanted in:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?ref_topic=1032998

It is called Campaigns.

Thanks